# Spring MVC + Ajax error 400

Tags: json, ajax, spring

I have a simple java application on Spring MVC and I send ajax request to Spring controller. When I set headers **"Accept", "application/json"** and **"Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8"** in AJAX call I get ***error 400*** in dubugger, when I delete it I get ***error 415***.

If I change controller method signature to ***public String logoutPage (@RequestBody String obyavleniye)*** I get JSON string. What problem can be with parse request in controller?

JS method:

```
$("#advertForm").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
        var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
        var obyavleniye = {
            title: "Title",
            price: "80",
            description: "desc",
            date: "2016-11-07 18:30:21",
            authorid: "2",
            category: "A",
            state: "new",
            img1: "http",
            img2: "http",
            img3: "http",
            img4: "http",
        };
        var post_data = JSON.stringify(obyavleniye);

        console.log(post_data);
        $.ajax({
            url : "/upload",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: post_data,
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
                xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
            },
            complete: function() {
                console.log("Sent");
            },
            success: function (response) {
                console.log("success");
                console.log("response" + response);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log("error");
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

Controller method:

```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value="/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String logoutPage (@RequestBody Advert obyavleniye) {
//    public String logoutPage (@RequestBody String obyavleniye) {
        System.out.println("Enter: " + obyavleniye);
        this.advertService.addAdvert(obyavleniye);
//        return "{\"msg\":\"success\"}";
        return "{\"title\":\"Title\",\"price\":\"80\",\"description\":\"normm\",\"date\":\"2016-11-07 18:30:21\",\"authorid\":\"2\",\"category\":\"A\",\"state\":\"new\",\"img1\":\"http\",\"img2\":\"http\",\"img3\":\"http\",\"img4\":\"http\"}";
    }
```

Comment: Please specify Advert  class properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My sample code.

**js**

```
  Company.prototype.saveCompanyLocation = function() {
        /* company */
        var companyIdx = $('#companyIdx').val();
        var locationIdx = $('#locationIdx').val();

        var data = {
            idx : locationIdx,

            postCode : $('#postCode').val(),
            address : $('#address').val(),
            detailAddress : $('#detailAddress').val(),

            tel : $('#tel').val(),
            fax : $('#fax').val(),
            email : $('#email').val(),
            language : $("#language").val(),

            latitude : $('#latitude').val(),
            longtitude : $('#longtitude').val()

        };

        data = JSON.stringify(data);

        $.ajax({
            url : "/gpim/company/settings/location/save/" + companyIdx,
            type : 'POST',
            data : data,
            contentType : 'application/json',

            success : function(response) {
                if (response == "success") {
                    document.location.reload(true);
                } else {
                    $("#editMsg").text("you can`t save location information.");
                }
            },
            error : function(request, status, error) {

            }
        });
    };
```

**controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/settings/location/save/{companyIdx}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String saveLocation(@PathVariable int companyIdx, @RequestBody CompanyLocation location) {
        Company company = companyService.findCompanyByIdx(companyIdx);

        company = companyService.saveCompanyLocation(company, location);

        if (company != null) {
            return "success";
        }

        return "fail";
    }
```

Comment: And where is difference? I can't understand why I get error.

Comment: You using HTTP header in "Accept", "application/json". then your controller take ( produces = "application/json") or use "contentType", "application/json". then  your controller take( consumes = "application/json" ). but you use two case.

Comment: And you use dataType : 'json' in js. it your controller return responseType. you use dataType : 'text' and var data = eval( '(' + response + ')' ); or if use 'json'. you can to search dataType : 'json' and server code. it long comment.

Comment: Thank you! I changed dataType: 'text' and it works. Maybe I changed something else but I thing it was the main issue.

Answer (score 1):

Do the below steps:

1) try to keep the jackson jar files in your classpath

2) eighter you have remove the datatype while sending ajax request i.e,

```
dataType : "json"
```

or you have to produce the application/json response as below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
```

3) Check your DTO or Advert class properties which type should be matched with incoming request. i.e request params should match with DTO members both names and type.

These are possible ways to avoid your case.